# easiest way to use a i/o callback within concurrent http-kit/get instances

Tags: concurrency, clojure, core.async, http-kit

I am launching a few hundreds concurrent `http-kit.client/get` requests provided with a callback to write results to a single file.

What would be a good way to deal with thread-safety? Using `chan`and `<!!` from `core.asyc`?

Here's the code I would consider :

```
(defn launch-async [channel url]                                                                                                                                
  (http/get url {:timeout 5000                                                                                                                                  
                 :user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0"}                                              
          (fn [{:keys [status headers body error]}]                                                                                                             
            (if error                                                                                                                                           
              (put! channel (json/generate-string {:url url :headers headers :status status}))                                                                  
              (put! channel (json/generate-string body))))))                                                                                                    

(defn process-async [channel func]                                                                                                                              
  (when-let [response (<!! channel)]                                                                                                                            
    (func response)))                                                                                                                                           

(defn http-gets-async [func urls]                                                                                                                               
  (let [channel (chan)]                                                                                                                                         
    (doall (map #(launch-async channel %) urls))                                                                                                                
    (process-async channel func)))
```

Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are already using core.async in your example, I thought I'd point out a few issues and how you can address them.  The other answer mentions using a more basic approach, and I agree wholeheartedly that a simpler approach is just fine.  However, with channels, you have a simple way of consuming the data which does not involve mapping over a vector, which will also grow large over time if you have many responses.  Consider the following issues and how we can fix them:

(1) Your current version will crash if your url list has more than 1024 elements.  There's an internal buffer for puts and takes that are asynchronous (i.e., `put!` and `take!` don't block but always return immediately), and the limit is 1024.  This is in place to prevent unbounded asynchronous usage of the channel.  To see for yourself, call `(http-gets-async println (repeat 1025 "http://blah-blah-asdf-fakedomain.com"))`.

What you want to do is to only put something on the channel when there's room to do so.  This is called back-pressure.  Taking a page from the excellent wiki on [go block best practices](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/wiki/Go-Block-Best-Practices), one clever way to do this from your http-kit callback is to use the `put!` callback option to launch your next http get; this will only happen when the `put!` immediately succeeds, so you will never have a situation where you can go beyond the channel's buffer:

```
(defn launch-async
  [channel [url & urls]]
  (when url
    (http/get url {:timeout 5000
                   :user-agent "Mozilla"}
              (fn [{:keys [status headers body error]}]
                (let [put-on-chan (if error
                                    (json/generate-string {:url url :headers headers :status status})
                                    (json/generate-string body))]
                  (put! channel put-on-chan (fn [_] (launch-async channel urls))))))))
```

(2) Next, you seem to be only processing one response.  Instead, use a go-loop:

```
(defn process-async
  [channel func]
  (go-loop []
    (when-let [response (<! channel)]
      (func response)
      (recur))))
```

(3) Here's your `http-gets-async` function.  I see no harm in adding a buffer here, as it should help you fire off a nice burst of requests at the beginning:

```
(defn http-gets-async
  [func urls]
  (let [channel (chan 1000)]
    (launch-async channel urls)
    (process-async channel func)))
```

Now, you have the ability to process an infinite number of urls, with back-pressure.  To test this, define a counter, and then make your processing function increment this counter to see your progress.  Using a localhost URL that is easy to bang on (wouldn't recommend firing off hundreds of thousands of requests to, say, google, etc.):

```
(def responses (atom 0))
(http-gets-async (fn [_] (swap! responses inc))
                 (repeat 1000000 "http://localhost:8000"))
```

As this is all asynchronous, your function will return immediately and you can look at `@responses` grow.

One other interesting thing you can do is instead of running your processing function in `process-async`, you could optionally apply it as a transducer on the channel itself.

```
(defn process-async
  [channel]
  (go-loop []
    (when-let [_ (<! channel)]
      (recur))))

(defn http-gets-async
  [func urls]
  (let [channel (chan 10000 (map func))] ;; <-- transducer on channel
    (launch-async channel urls)
    (process-async channel)))
```

There are many ways to do this, including constructing it so that the channel closes (note that above, it stays open).  You have `java.util.concurrent` primitives to help in this regard if you like, and they are quite easy to use.  The possibilities are very numerous.

Comment: I would have expected `launch-asyc` to overflow when provided with a big urls sequence. Why is it not the case? (I assume it because it's given as an official suggestion). Thanks

Comment: another thing. It writes to a file as long as I send code to the repl (boot repl), yet nothing happens when I wrap the same code inside a `-main` function and run it  as a script. Is it supposed to behave that way? Thanks

Comment: @user3639782 each element taken from the sequence generated by the `repeat` function is produced "on demand", i.e., the sequence is lazy, and can in fact be infinite. So, the list of urls takes up literally almost no memory. Regarding your other question, I'm not sure what you mean about writing to a file.

Comment: I understand `repeat` produces a lazy seq, yet `launch-async`is non-tail recursive

Comment: @user3639782 It's not recursive at all -- it does not call itself. The callback for put! calls launch-async , so it is not recursive. It is similar to continuation passing style (CPS).

Answer (score 1):

This is simple enough that I wouldn't use core.async for it. You can do this with an atom storing use a vector of the responses, then have a separate thread reading the contents of atom until it's seen all of the responses. Then, in your http-kit callback, you could just `swap!` the response into the atom directly.

If you do want to use core.async, I'd recommend a buffered channel to keep from blocking your http-kit thread pool.